# Increment in while loop not happening after OR

Tags: while-loop, increment

Imagine you've got a while loop with an OR condition of two values. The second value has an increment (`++`). If the first value is `true` increment from the second value never seems to occur.

Let's take a look at a piece of code:

```
bool iterationPassed = false;
while (!iterationPassed || ++retries <= 3)
if(somethingHappened)
  iterationPassed = true;
```

Okay, I'm very aware that this is logical. If the first value is true, there's an OR statement, why would there be a need to check the other value. But in this case, the other value is a result of another step (`++`) and that step never happened. So I guess incrementing or doing any sort of operation in a complex condition is a very bad practice? Also, is this language specific?

Comment: this is http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation Some languages have Eager operators, so yes, it is language specific.

Comment: aah, I was worried I was just plain stupid I didn't know this. Now I feel a bit better :)

Comment: Also, in your case, you can simply reverse your conditions to put the increment on the left.

Comment: Which I already did. I just had the urge to share this. Thanks a lot.